# A rare crash is occurred in my project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing a rare crash in my android app.

I searched on Google and everywhere but all other guys are saying it's an issue with Gradle plugin 2.2.0-alpha2.

I downgraded the Gradle plugin but the issue is not resolved.
Please help me to solve this issue.

My Logcat is:

> Throwing new exception 'length=833; index=1523' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=833; index=1523
>   08-17 11:41:07.445 418-418/com.nagainfo.vro A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1344]   at void com.nagainfo.vro.login_reg.UserLoginFragment.signin(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.view.View) (UserLoginFragment.java:352)
>   08-17 11:41:07.445 418-418/com.nagainfo.vro A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1344]   at void com.nagainfo.vro.login_reg.UserLoginFragment.onClick(android.view.View) (UserLoginFragment.java:211)

Comment: please code of `UserLoginFragment`

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException doesn't really count as rare...

Comment: This doesn't seem an issue with gradle plugin version

Comment: You need to make modifications to your questions as per: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @lelloman ,can you pls explain what is exactly for this crashes

Comment: an array has a size, say 5, you ask for index 7, the array gets pissed off and crash your app

Comment: @ lelloman actually i didnt use any in  my login Fragmnet

Comment: Please  post code of     UserLoginFragment asap.

Comment: yup sure ,will post it immediately

Comment: maybe you pissed off a dead array and now its ghost is haunting you

Comment: no one can help you without posting your code. my friend

Answer (score 0):

check your data  array/model is not null

```
 if (abc != null)
 {
           //set your data
 }
```